# Is there a simple word to describe two quantities whose difference is constant?

Tags: terminology

Suppose I have two temperatures in an experiment, $\theta_a$ and $\theta_b$, which theory predicts should be equal up to an offset.

Is there a simple word to describe this relationship? I have considered the following:

- $\theta_a$ and $\theta_b$ are separated by a constant offset
- $\theta_a-\theta_b$ is constant
- $\theta_a$ is equal to $\theta_b$ plus a constant offset

None of these sound particularly natural. Is there a simple word to describe this kind of relationship?

Comment: +1 Interesting question, but isn't this more of a math question for https://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Those are all equivalent descriptions; which you choose would depend on who you're talking to, but if one generic choice must be made, I'd probably go for the first of your three options.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to say that $\theta_a$ is ["big-o"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of $\theta_b$, but this is a broader/weaker relationship than the one you're describing.

Essentially, $f(x) \in O(g(x))$ if 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|} < \infty.$$

Hence $O(g(x))$ describes a huge set of functions, one of which is $x + c$ for some constant $c$